# Rest API axios error handling in redux-saga using catch

Tags: reactjs, redux, error-handling, axios, redux-saga

On inspecting in Chrome.In network i get response

```
{"status":"error","data":{"message":"Unauthorized"}}
```

Is there any issue in catching axios error.HOw should i handle this issue.
I get succesfull response on authorised login.

---

Redux-Saga Generator function

---

```
export function* loginUserSaga(action) {
  yield put(actions.loginStart());
  const loginData = {
    'email': action.email,
    'password': action.password
  };
  let url ="api/v1/login";
  console.log("Saga-send:",loginData);
  try {
    const response = yield axios.post(url, loginData);
    console.log("Saga-recived:",response);
    yield localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.access_token);
    yield put(
      actions.loginSuccess(response.data.idToken)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Saga-error:",error);  
    yield put(actions.loginFail(error));
  }
}
```

---

Console

---

```
Saga-send: {email: "123456@gmail.com", password: "assasaassasa"} 
Saga-error: Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

also gets an error on axios.post()

Comment: I think you need  `console.log("Saga-error:",error.response);` Check this discussion https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

Answer (score 3):

```
import Api from './path/to/api'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function fetchProductsApi() {
  return Api.fetch('/products')
    .then(response => ({ response }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }))
}

function* fetchProducts() {
  const { response, error } = yield call(fetchProductsApi)
  if (response)
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products: response })
  else
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })
}
```

Here is the [Documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html)