# Handling Errors with Custom Axios and redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios, interceptor, redux-saga

I have the following pipeline in my React App

saga.js :

```
function* handleGetTrack(action: ReturnType<typeof selectTrack>) {
  try {
    const getTrackResponse = yield httpGetTrack(action.payload)
    yield console.log(getTrackResponse)

     getTrackResponse.status === 200
       ? yield put(trackSelected(getTrackResponse.data))
       : yield put(selectTrackError('Track Not Found (Get)'))
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error && err.stack) {
      yield put(selectTrackError(err.stack))
    } else {
      yield put(selectTrackError('An unknown error occured.'))
    }
  }
}
```

Api.js

```
export function httpGetTrack(trackId) {
  return customAxios.get(`${URL}/tracks/${trackId}`)
}
```

customAxios.js :

```
export const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
  timeout: 10000,
})
customAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response
  },

  function(error) {
    const errorResponse = error.response
    if (isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse)) {
      return resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error)
    }
    return error.response
  }
)
```

Like this everything works fine, In fact in my saga.js I can make the `console.log(getTrackResponse)` print the error well,

However in the Axios documentation it says tu use  `return Promise.reject(error)` instead of `return error.response`

Why is that ?? Am i doing well or wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `call` effect?  For example:

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

...

const getTrackResponse = yield call(httpGetTrack, action.payload);

...
```

When you define your interceptor you should also follow the Axios docs

```
function(error) {
    const errorResponse = error.response
    ...
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Api from './path/to/api'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function fetchProductsApi() {
  return Api.fetch('/products')
    .then(response => ({ response }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }))
}

function* fetchProducts() {
  const { response, error } = yield call(fetchProductsApi)
  if (response)
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products: response })
  else
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })
}
```

[Documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html)

[Here is an answer for a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694136/rest-api-axios-error-handling-in-redux-saga-using-catch/65458940#65458940)